# Store the Image in Document Directory path with same name and extension

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have one url which download image from the server
I am getting it as a `NSData` and store it to my local path.

```
thedata = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",[CNPlayerURL getUniqueIdAvailable],imageUrl]]];

[thedata writeToFile:localFilePath atomically:YES];
```

Now my question is can I have downloaded name and the extension for the Image that i am storing in my path. because now my `localFilePath` is having Document Directory path append with imagename(I am giving it one unique id with a `.jpg` extension)

like when i use my url in my browser

```
http:/myserverurl/groupid/199/blob
```

it is downloading this image:

[image]

now i want to save with this name and extension

Comment: I do not understand your question? Do you want to include the full url in the file name? Or can you re-phrase your question? Give some examples of what you want to achieve?

Comment: take the `lastPathComponent` from your URL and append it to `DocumentDirectory' path while writing it to local.

Comment: do you want image name with ext. in your image url ?

Comment: for example when i use url on browser it is download one image with name and extension like test.jpg but how can i get that name and extension from the data

Comment: NSString *imgPath = [imageUrl lastPathComponent];

Comment: can you all see my edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get "Downloadable File name" using `suggestedFilename` method of `NSURLResponse` like this.

```
-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSLog(@"Downloadable FileName: %@",[response suggestedFilename]);
    NSLog(@"Downloadable MIMEType: %@",[response MIMEType]);
    NSLog(@"Downloadable ContentLength: %lld",[response expectedContentLength]);
    [webData setLength:0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *jpgFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/%@", YourDirectoryName,[imageUrl lastPathComponent]];
NSString *getImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:jpgFilePath];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:getImagePath]) {
        NSData *data1 = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)];
        [data1 writeToFile:getImagePath atomically:YES];
    }
```